# problem with Infopath Form services

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

1. I want to have some url for my infopath form and give that link to user instead of going to form library and click new...how is it possible?
2. Also when I created Infopath form I have given some text fields and button, I don't want the Infopath services buttons(Save,save as...) how I cna remove those?

Any suggestions would really be appreciated...Thanks

Comment: I found the answer of my second problem ...Tools->Form options->uncheck show toolbar at top and bottom

Answer (score 0):

You can publish an InfoPath form to a network share and give your users a link to it (or use a file:// url on a webpage). Another option is to figure out the URL to the form within form services (whats the actual URL when they click on the new button) and send out that link as the official URL. Both options have advantages (and disadvantages) so make sure to evaluate them both with respect to what you are trying to accomplish and the environment (ie - are you just trying to save your users a click or is there some other reason you need the 'new' URL).

Comment: The second method you said...when I click on new button it generates list itemid also in URL...so that would work only one time and once they submit it ...you can't use it again.....nd the first method u suggested...how i can publish on network share...when we publish we get three options....doc. library,admin,content type..what do u mean by that...could you elaborate....

Comment: i don't want my users to go to doc. libarry i want the from to be on some page....like forms generally do...and in the back end its going to doc. library so thats diff....but all i want to show user is form where they can click and submit...everytime they come to that page...

Comment: Sorry I blanked out on the forms SERVICES part and answered based on a regular InfoPath form (which can be published to a share). 

You still might be able to grab the URL for the new button, although you might have to read the source to get it. I believe the ID is assigned after you click on the button. If you read through the source you might be able to unwind the actual calls/URL before the ID is assigned (but it probably is not going to be easy).

Answer (score 0):

1.) Format your URL like this:
https://SPSITE/sites/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?xsnLocation=https://SPSITE/sites/FORMLIBRARY/forms/template.xsn?DefaultItemOpen=1

2.) You found already! ; )